# ROS Can't find my executable - install_isolated

Tags: ros, rosrun, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running ROS Indigo on Raspbian I run "catkin_make_isolated --install" and I cannot seem to run my C++ node with:

```
pi@rospi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ rosrun eyebot_testing eybot_testing_node
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named eybot_testing_node below /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/eyebot_testing
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt file that compiles just fine.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(eyebot_testing)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /home/pi/eyebot/include
)

add_executable(eyebot_testing_node src/eyebot_testing_node.cpp)

find_library(eyebot_testing_node /home/pi/eyebot/lib)
target_link_libraries(eyebot_testing_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   wiringPi
   mpsse
   X11
   lirc_client
   m
   opencv_core
   opencv_highgui
   opencv_imgproc
   eyebot
 )
```

My source statements are also correct, these are the two lines in my .basrc file:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
```

Upon attempting to locate my binary (as the compilation and linking was successful), I can only find them in `/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/eyebot_testing/lib/eyebot_testing/eyebot_testing_node`

If I attempt to source from there using the devel setup.bash script it won't find the package at all.

Ideas?

**Update:**

I added this for installation and it didn't change where the binary ended up, same result.

```
## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
 install(TARGETS eyebot_testing_node
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

## Mark cpp header files for installation
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232808/ros-can%27t-find-my-executable---install_isolated/) by [Tardoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26613/tardoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2016-04-25**:
You don not seem to have install targets in your CMakeLists which is why it won't put anything in the install dir.

**Comment by [Tardoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26613/tardoe/) on 2016-04-25**:
I added the installation target info as below and it didn't help - care to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the posted CMake code you reuse the variable name `eyebot_testing_node`. After creating the executable target you are overwriting it with the `find_library` call (which I don't know why you are calling this function in the first place).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tardoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26613/tardoe/) on 2016-04-25**:
Ah that seems to have fixed it. I added the find_library() call to locate my libeyebot.a library file but simply commenting out that line appears to have worked.